# Can't click on the start button on Desktop Computer and Taskbar doesn't let me click it

Tags: windows, windows-10, desktop, desktop-computer, window

I've had this problem for about 1 year now and can't seem to resolve.

When I click on my start button on my Desktop (Windows 10) nothing happens. When I right click on my taskbar settings > Settings opens up and closes quickly. Nothing on start works. Currently i had to go to explorer and copy the settings icon to my desktop so I have access to it. All I can do now is right click on the start button and right click and click run and look for the path.

I've had geek squad remote into my Desktop and claimed they fixed it but of course the problem still occurs.

Would be nice to get this resolved or i would have to migrate my Desktop to a Mac so we have peace of mind a reliability.

Edit: Same thing happens in safe mode.

Forgot to tell you that this Desktop has been wiped clean and everything put back on it

Comment: Does it happen while in Safe Mode? [Edit] your question instead of submitting a temporary comment

Comment: Updated Question

Comment: 1. Try to repair the Windows OS using SFC and DISM, https://www.windowscentral.com/how-use-dism-command-line-utility-repair-windows-10-image. 2. If those don't fix the issue, download the latest Windows 10 ISO from Microsoft and put on a USB drive with Create Windows 10 installation media, https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10 , and reinstall Windows 10, **keeping files**. That usually is safe,  but better would be to make a full disk image before reinstalling, to have a fallback,

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Can i use the SFC and DISM with ought backing up my Desktop? Will it just work?

Comment: So far, I've never had issue with SFC and DISM repairs... That said, *make a disk image* anyway, because  misteaks happen (oops...).

Comment: @DrMoishePippik not used to windows. Make a disk image of the whole desktop? How would i do that? also would i need to move it to a usb drive?

Comment: No, a **disk image**, or a **drive image**, is a copy of the entire HDD or SSD, not the "desktop". How? Use software: https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/best-disk-image-software/ .  @BigJoe, what OS *did * you use? Linux uses dd, Macs https://geekflare.com/disk-cloning-software-for-mac/

Comment: @DrMoishePippik DISM and SFC didn't resolve the issue but reinstall windows 10 while keeping files etc.. fixed the issue. I just reinstalled today about 1 hour ago and its resolved. Thanks again